# Regex help: My regex pattern will match invalid Dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, regex, linq, dictionary

I hope you guys can help me out.
I'm using C# .Net 4.0

I want validate file structure like

```
 
const string dataFileScr = @"
Start 0
{
    Next = 1
    Author = rk
    Date = 2011-03-10
/*  Description = simple */
}

PZ 11
{
IA_return()
}

GDC 7
{
    Message = 6
    Message = 7
        Message = 8
        Message = 8
    RepeatCount = 2
    ErrorMessage = 10
    ErrorMessage = 11
    onKey[5] = 6
    onKey[6] = 4
    onKey[9] = 11
}
";
```

So far I managed to build this regex pattern

```
 
const string patternFileScr = @"
^                           
((?:\[|\s)*                  

     (?<Section>[^\]\r\n]*)     
 (?:\])*                     
 (?:[\r\n]{0,}|\Z))         
(
    (?:\{)                  ### !! improve for .ini file, dont take { 
    (?:[\r\n]{0,}|\Z)           
        (                          # Begin capture groups (Key Value Pairs)
        (?!\}|\[)                    # Stop capture groups if a } is found; new section  

          (?:\s)*                     # Line with space
          (?<Key>[^=]*?)            # Any text before the =, matched few as possible
          (?:[\s]*=[\s]*)                     # Get the = now
          (?<Value>[^\r\n]*)        # Get everything that is not an Line Changes


         (?:[\r\n]{0,})
         )*                        # End Capture groups
    (?:[\r\n]{0,})
    (?:\})?
    (?:[\r\n\s]{0,}|\Z)
)*

                ";
```

and c#

```
  Dictionary <string, Dictionary<string, string>> DictDataFileScr
            = (from Match m in Regex.Matches(dataFileScr,
                                            patternFileScr,
                                            RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace | RegexOptions.Multiline)
               select new
               {
                   Section = m.Groups["Section"].Value,

                   kvps = (from cpKey in m.Groups["Key"].Captures.Cast().Select((a, i) => new { a.Value, i })
                           join cpValue in m.Groups["Value"].Captures.Cast().Select((b, i) => new { b.Value, i }) on cpKey.i equals cpValue.i
                           select new KeyValuePair(cpKey.Value, cpValue.Value)).OrderBy(_ => _.Key)
                           .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value)

               }).ToDictionary(itm => itm.Section, itm => itm.kvps);
```

It works for

```
 
const string dataFileScr = @"
Start 0
{
    Next = 1
    Author = rk
    Date = 2011-03-10
/*  Description = simple */
}

GDC 7
{
    Message = 6
    RepeatCount = 2
    ErrorMessage = 10
    onKey[5] = 6
    onKey[6] = 4
    onKey[9] = 11
}
";
```

in other words

```
 
Section1
{
key1=value1
key2=value2
}

Section2
{
key1=value1
key2=value2
}
```

, but

1. not for multiple keyname,  i want group by key and output

```
DictDataFileScr["GDC 7"]["Message"] = "6|7|8|8"
DictDataFileScr["GDC 7"]["ErrorMessage"] = "10|11"
```

2. not work for .ini file like

```
....
[Section1]
key1 = value1
key2 = value2

[Section2]
key1 = value1
key2 = value2
...
```

3. dont see next section after

```
....
PZ 11
{
IA_return()
}
.....
```

Comment: if you can reduce your case to a few lines maybe people can help you better

Comment: can you send some other examples

Comment: Soo ah, you wanna tell me why `\s*(\[[^\S\n]*)?(?<Section>\w+(?:[^\S\n]+ \w+)*)(?(1)[^\S\n]*\]|)\s*(?(1)|\{)(?:\s*(?:\/\*.*?\*\/|(?<Key>\w[\w\[\]]*(?:[^\S\n]+[\w\[\]]+)*)[^\S\n]*=[^\S\n]*(?<Value>[^\n]*)|(?(1)|[^{}\n]*))\s*)*(?(1)|\})` with just single line ('.' dot means newline as well) doesen't work for ya man, I mean I'm throwing you a bone here. I read about the Collections in dot net, this should absolutely do it. I can be hired to do the most challenging things you can imagine. The sublety of this regex is sublime. Its flows, simple and powerful, if you know what your looking at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a complete rework of the regex in C#.

**Assumptions :** (tell me if one of them is false or all are false)

1. An INI file section can only have key/value pair lines in its body
2. In an non INI file section, function calls can't have any parameters

**Regex flags :**
RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace | RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.Singleline

---

**Input test:**

```
const string dataFileScr = @"
Start 0
{
    Next = 1
    Author = rk
    Date = 2011-03-10
/*  Description = simple */
}

PZ 11
{
IA_return()
}

GDC 7
{
    Message = 6
    Message = 7
        Message = 8
        Message = 8
    RepeatCount = 2
    ErrorMessage = 10
    ErrorMessage = 11
    onKey[5] = 6
    onKey[6] = 4
    onKey[9] = 11
}

[Section1]
key1 = value1
key2 = value2

[Section2]
key1 = value1
key2 = value2
";
```

**Reworked regex:**

```
const string patternFileScr = @"
(?<Section>                                                              (?# Start of a non ini file section)
  (?<SectionName>[\w ]+)\s*                                              (?# Capture section name)
     {                                                                   (?# Match but don't capture beginning of section)
        (?<SectionBody>                                                  (?# Capture section body. Section body can be empty)
         (?<SectionLine>\s*                                              (?# Capture zero or more line(s) in the section body)
         (?:                                                             (?# A line can be either a key/value pair, a comment or a function call)
            (?<KeyValuePair>(?<Key>[\w\[\]]+)\s*=\s*(?<Value>[\w-]*))    (?# Capture key/value pair. Key and value are sub-captured separately)
            |
            (?<Comment>/\*.+?\*/)                                        (?# Capture comment)
            |
            (?<FunctionCall>[\w]+\(\))                                   (?# Capture function call. A function can't have parameters though)
         )\s*                                                            (?# Match but don't capture white characters)
         )*                                                              (?# Zero or more line(s), previously mentionned in comments)
        )
     }                                                                   (?# Match but don't capture beginning of section)
)
|
(?<Section>                                                              (?# Start of an ini file section)
  \[(?<SectionName>[\w ]+)\]                                             (?# Capture section name)
  (?<SectionBody>                                                        (?# Capture section body. Section body can be empty)
     (?<SectionLine>                                                     (?# Capture zero or more line(s) in the section body. Only key/value pair allowed.)
        \s*(?<KeyValuePair>(?<Key>[\w\[\]]+)\s*=\s*(?<Value>[\w-]+))\s*  (?# Capture key/value pair. Key and value are sub-captured separately)
     )*                                                                  (?# Zero or more line(s), previously mentionned in comments)
  )
)
";
```

---

**Discussion**
The regex is build to match either non INI file sections ***(1)*** or INI file section  ***(2)***.

***(1) Non-INI file sections*** These sections are composed by a section name followed by a body enclosed by { and }.
The section name con contain either letters, digits or spaces.
The section body is composed by zero or more lines. A line can be either a key/value pair (key = value), a comment (/* Here is a comment */) or a function call with no parameters (my_function()).

***(2) INI file sections***
These sections are composed by a section name enclosed by [ and ] followed by zero or more key/value pairs. Each pair is on one line.

Comment: @sln i would return you the same question for your Perl code. I made all this stuff for detailing the answer. I don't want to just drop a response the OP won't understand.All named match group are there for the sake of clarity.

Comment: @Stephen by 'for so little' I mean `<Key> \s* = *\s <Value>` does not restrict this pair to 1 line. In order to extract meaningfull data, the 3 alternations must procede `XXX { (?: comments | key = value | junk_line )* }` Of these, `k/v pairs and junk_line` must be processed (consumed) on a line basis, otherwise this section will fail in a hail of backtracking. Also, `VALUE` can be anything or nothing (on a line basis), it can't be restricted to `[\w-]+` as you have here and `\s*=\s*` is not sustainable.

Answer (score 2):

Do yourself and your sanity a favor and learn how to use [GPLex](http://gplex.codeplex.com/) and [GPPG](http://gppg.codeplex.com/).  They are the closest thing that C# has to Lex and Yacc (or Flex and Bison, if you prefer) which are the proper tools for this job.

Regular expressions are great tools for performing robust string matching, but when you want to match structures of strings that's when you need a "grammar".  This is what a parser is for.  GPLex takes a bunch of regular expressions and generates a super-fast lexer.  GPPG takes the grammar you write and generates a super-fast parser.

Trust me, learn how to use these tools ... or any other tools like them.  You'll be glad you did.

Comment: Without knowing a grammar is involved this is a premature statement.

Comment: @sln, what do you mean? What is the regex supposed to be in the OP? I'd say that regex describes (or tries to describe) the structure of the input text: in other words, _there's_ the grammar.

Comment: @Bart, there was the `{}` characters involved in the sample data. I can't jump to the conslusion there is a grammar. Is there any if/then/else involved in grammar? Because, regular expressions have that and possesive quantifiers.

Answer (score 0):

***# 2. not work for .ini file like***

Won't work because as stated by your regular expression, an { is required after [Section].
Your regex will match if you have something like this :

```
[Section]
{
key = value
}
```

Comment: Nah, it won't stop at the ending `}`. His regex blows right past to the final `}` due to his classes.

Comment: i have made a test.Putting my sample section at the end of r4ph's code, the section is matched. With no { it is not. Tested with C#

Comment: Oh, maybe he fixed it then. One of his bullet points used to state that as a problem. There are numerous problems with the regex, too much to adress. Its better to rewrite. Unfortunately, people that know regex don't get paid to do it.

Comment: Confirmed, nothing has changed, it still overunns all boundry's.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample in Perl. Perl doesen't have named capture arrays. Probably because of backtracking.
Maybe you can pick something out of the regex though. This assumes there is no nesting of {} bracktes.

**Edit** Never content to leave well enough alone, a revised version is below.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = '
Start 0
{
    Next = 1
    Author = rk
    Date = 2011-03-10
 /*  Description = simple
 */
}

asdfasdf

PZ 11
{
IA_return()
}

[ section 5 ]
  this = that
[ section 6 ]
  this_ = _that{hello() hhh = bbb}

TOC{}

GDC 7
{
    Message = 6
    Message = 7
        Message = 8
        Message = 8
    RepeatCount = 2
    ErrorMessage = 10
    ErrorMessage = 11
    onKey[5] = 6
    onKey[6] = 4
    onKey[9] = 11
}
';


use re 'eval';

my $rx = qr/

\s*
( \[ [^\S\n]* )?                     # Grp 1  optional ini section delimeter '['
(?<Section> \w+ (?:[^\S\n]+ \w+)* )  # Grp 2  'Section'
(?(1) [^\S\n]* \] |)                 # Condition, if we matched '[' then look for ']'
\s* 

(?<Body>                   # Grp 3 'Body' (for display only)
   (?(1)| \{ )                   # Condition, if we're not a ini section then look for '{'

   (?{ print "Section: '$+{Section}'\n" })  # SECTION debug print, remove in production

   (?:                           # _grp_
       \s*                           # whitespace
       (?:                              # _grp_
            \/\* .*? \*\/                    # some comments
          |                               # OR ..
                                             # Grp 4 'Key'  (tested with print, Perl doesen't have named capture arrays)
            (?<Key> \w[\w\[\]]* (?:[^\S\n]+ [\w\[\]]+)* )
            [^\S\n]* = [^\S\n]*              # =
            (?<Value> [^\n]* )               # Grp 5 'Value' (tested with print)

            (?{ print "  k\/v: '$+{Key}' = '$+{Value}'\n" })  # KEY,VALUE debug print, remove in production
          |                               # OR ..
            (?(1)| [^{}\n]* )                # any chars except newline and [{}] on the condition we're not a ini section
        )                               # _grpend_
        \s*                          # whitespace
    )*                           # _grpend_  do 0 or more times 
   (?(1)| \} )                   # Condition, if we're not a ini section then look for '}'
)
/x;


while ($str =~ /$rx/xsg)
{
    print "\n";
    print "Body:\n'$+{Body}'\n";
    print "=========================================\n";
}

__END__
```

Output

```
Section: 'Start 0'
  k/v: 'Next' = '1'
  k/v: 'Author' = 'rk'
  k/v: 'Date' = '2011-03-10'

Body:
'{
    Next = 1
    Author = rk
    Date = 2011-03-10
 /*  Description = simple
 */
}'
=========================================
Section: 'PZ 11'

Body:
'{
IA_return()
}'
=========================================
Section: 'section 5'
  k/v: 'this' = 'that'

Body:
'this = that
'
=========================================
Section: 'section 6'
  k/v: 'this_' = '_that{hello() hhh = bbb}'

Body:
'this_ = _that{hello() hhh = bbb}

'
=========================================
Section: 'TOC'

Body:
'{}'
=========================================
Section: 'GDC 7'
  k/v: 'Message' = '6'
  k/v: 'Message' = '7'
  k/v: 'Message' = '8'
  k/v: 'Message' = '8'
  k/v: 'RepeatCount' = '2'
  k/v: 'ErrorMessage' = '10'
  k/v: 'ErrorMessage' = '11'
  k/v: 'onKey[5]' = '6'
  k/v: 'onKey[6]' = '4'
  k/v: 'onKey[9]' = '11'

Body:
'{
    Message = 6
    Message = 7
        Message = 8
        Message = 8
    RepeatCount = 2
    ErrorMessage = 10
    ErrorMessage = 11
    onKey[5] = 6
    onKey[6] = 4
    onKey[9] = 11
}'
=========================================
```